# How to specify alias on YamlMember in YamlDotNet?

Tags: c#, yaml, yamldotnet

I need to deserialize the following YAML to my custom type. YamlAlias attribute seems to be obsolete, so I replaced it with YamlMember. It fails on deserializing the following YAML with the below exception:

> ```
>     host:
>       properties:
>         mem_size: 2048  MB
> ```
>
> YamlDotNet.Core.YamlException : (Line: 21, Col: 13, Idx: 524) - (Line: 21, Col: 13, Idx: 524): Exception during deserialization
>     ----> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException : Property 'mem_size' not found on type 'Toscana.Domain.HostProperties'.

```
public class Host
{
    public HostProperties Properties { get; set; }
}

public class HostProperties
{
    [YamlMember(typeof(DigitalStorage))]
    public string MemSize { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Alias` is a property of the `YamlMemberAttribute` class, it's not in the constructor. Now, I don't know how your `DigitalStorage` class looks like and whether a `string` will be successfully deserialized into it (I doubt it), but since your question is to add an alias, this is how you do it:

```
public class HostProperties
{
    [YamlMember(typeof(DigitalStorage), Alias = "mem_size")]
    public string MemSize { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How do you set an alies for the `HostProperties` class? In XML I would use `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "HP")]`?

Comment: @MrCalvin, I don't think you can decorate classes themselves, only instances of classes. The root class won't be visible in the serialized YAML, only the properties within it. So to give `HostProperties` an alias you would have to decorate the `Properties` property within the `Host` class with `YamlMember(Alias = "properties")`.